# How do i check cassandra and solr is up?

Tags: solr, cassandra, datastax

I just installed `datastax 2.2.2` on my `ubuntu:12.04` machine from `tarball`
I started services using `bin/dse cassandra -s`. I din't set any env variables.But it starts the service.

```
bin/dse/bin/nodetool status
```

It lists out list of valid commands where status is not there. How do i verify my cassandra and solr is up?

AM i missing something? ANy ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    bin/nodetool ring -h localhost
```

It will return about the solr and cassandra status.

Answer (score 4):

nodetool status should work. DSE 4.6 is the latest version, why are you on 2.2?

Watch your system and output logs as the node starts up to see gossip hints etc. It will end with something like:

> done waiting for other nodes

You can also check if the service is running --

```
ps -ef | grep dse
```

Comment: If i see this line at the end, then is it mean everything fine?

Comment: That's the end of the startup process. If theres no errors and cassandra and search come up, you're good.

Comment: Yes I tried with 4.5.2. It works. But whats the problem with 2.2.2 phact?

Answer (score 2):

**nodetool status**

Run this command in terminal and you will get all information related
IP Address,
Load,
Tokens,
Owns,
Host,
ID,
and Rack